# Delete multiple values in a list of python

Tags: python

I have an index of list elements that I want to delete. How can I do that ?

For example, if my original list is a=[1,2,3,4,5,6] and my index list is [2,3]. I want the elements 3,4 to be removed

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to delete the indices, you can do the following two methods:

In place:

```
for index in sorted(indices, reversed=True):
    del a[index]
```

out of place:

```
new_a = [el for index, el in enumerate(a) if index not in indices]
```

The reason why we sort for the in-place version is because deleting from the back doesn't modify the referenced elements in the front (note that this breaks with negative indexing).

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
a = a[:2] + a[4:]
print(a)
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```